# Image won't shrink to fit DIV with responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am struggling to get an image (`featuredpic`) to respect the maximum-height bounds on its parent DIVs. The maximum dimensions of `mainCategory` is 1000px wide and 300px high (set by outside constraints) and when the page width shrinks, the 10:3 proportion is maintained as it shrinks with no issue. But, the  featuredpic (native size of 250x250px) will not change at all. I've tried every combination of max-height, height, etc. set as percentages with no success. Only setting a height in pixels will have an effect, but that won't work with the responsive design. I even inserted the `featuredPicContainer` DIV to try to help control it, but it didn't make any visible change in my implementation. I'm assuming it's something to do with my use of absolute positioning, but I can't figure out an alternate solution. Any suggestions?

```css
/* And the CSS: */

.mainCategory {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainPic {
  display: block;
}

.mainGradient {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.mainTextWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #eef7f6;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.mainText {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mainSectionWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: table;
}

.featuredPicWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #eef7f6;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 85%;
  right: 0;
}

.featuredPicContainer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.featuredPic {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCategory">
  <a href="link">
    <img class="mainPic" src="background.jpg">
    <img class="mainGradient" src="gradient.jpg">
    <div class="mainTextWrapper">
      <div class="mainText">FEATURED PICTURE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="featuredPicWrapper">
      <div class="featuredPicContainer">
        <img class="featuredPic" src="featuredpic.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post youe example in a working sandbox like jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I'm not 100% sure why it worked, but it did. I removed the `display: table;` from `.featuredPicWrapper` and added `float:left` and `width:100%` to `.featuredPicContainer` and that resolved the issue. Removing the Display and adding the Float were key to allowing it to resize, and adding the width kept it centered over the background as I intended.